# How can you see a list of python modules that YOU imported in Jupyter notebook with asterisk?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The title says it all. How do you see it? Sometimes I import every method in a python module with asterisk, and I would like to see a list of all the methods from that module in Jupyter notebook. Is there a simple command for this?

Comment: Did you check this in notebook?  e. g. `!pip3 freeze | grep -e  "numpy*" -e "scipy*" `

Comment: You could do a non-starred import and `dir`. You risk that the module name overwrites one of you variable names. In that case, `import foo as whatever` then `dir(whatever)`.

Comment: What I wanted to do was to see a list of ALL the modules that I PERSONALLY imported on Jupyter notebook interactively. But I appreciate all your comments :)